# Cannot read property 'storageKey' of undefined

Tags: angular

I have a shopping cart and I only want the products to be set if they don't already exist in localStorage. If the product is already in localStorage, then no new product should be added. Later I will update the quantity if the product already exists in localStorage but I haven't reached that step yet. When I try to set the item when the id isn't in localStorage, I get the TypeError: `Cannot read property 'storageKey' of undefined`

```
storageKey = 'MyDataStorageKey';

public onSubmit(id, quantity, product_name) {

  var data = {
    id,
    quantity,
    product_name,
  };

  var retrieverObject = localStorage.getItem('items');
  var retrieveObject = JSON.parse(retrieverObject);
  this.items.push(data);

  retrieveObject.forEach(function (el) {
    alert("This is the storage id " + el.id);
    if (el.id == id) {
      alert(el.id + " same product");
    } else {
      alert("this id is not in storage ");
      //error returns for the following line of code
      localStorage.setItem(this.storageKey, JSON.stringify(this.items));
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using arrow function in order to preserve `this` context in `forEach` callback:

```
retrieveObject.forEach(function(el){
                         ||
                         \/
retrieveObject.forEach(el => {
```

Comment: Using the arrow function and putting this.items.push(data); in to the else condition fixed the problem!

Comment: The product still gets set after all even when localStorage is set. It's not working as intended but the error message is suppressed.